# Enable-PSRemoting on Windows Server 2008 R2 error

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, workgroup

When giving the command Enable-PSSRemoting with or without the -Force parameter this error occurs

```
Set-WSManQuickConfig : More data is available.
At line:50 char:33
+           Set-WSManQuickConfig <<<<  -force
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-WSManQuickConfig],
InvalidOperationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
WsManError,Microsoft.WSMan.Management.SetWSManQuickConfigCommand
```

I've looked at this resource for help in solving this problem http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/ and some others.

But it seems my solution is not in any of those. I have checked regarding run as administrationen, checked that the local admin is not disabled or have a blank password, also updated the registry key regarding the LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy. Set the trustedhosts to *

This is done locally on a Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, ENU x64

Result from: winrm quickconfig as suggest by @tony roth

```
WSManFault
Message = More data is available.
Error number:  -2147024662 0x800700EA
More data is available.
```

Result from: winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener

```
Listener
Address = *
Transport = HTTP
Port = 5985
Hostname
Enabled = true
URLPrefix = wsman
CertificateThumbprint
ListeningOn = 10.108.x.x, 127.0.0.1, ::1, x:0:5ef5:79fb:6b:3590:f593:f4eb, x::5efe:10.108.11.20%13, fe80::6b
```

:x:f593:f4eb%11, x::8418:7b59:e7ff:ccd4%12

Result from: dir WSMan:\localhost\shell

```
AllowRemoteShellAccess    true
IdleTimeout               180000
MaxConcurrentUsers        5
MaxShellRunTime           2147483647
MaxProcessesPerShell      15
MaxMemoryPerShellMB       150
MaxShellsPerUser          5
```

Result from: dir WSMan:\localhost\client

```
Name            Value                                        Type
----            -----                                        ----
NetworkDelayms            5000                               System.String
URLPrefix                 wsman                              System.String
AllowUnencrypted          false                              System.String
Auth                                                         Container
DefaultPorts                                                 Container
TrustedHosts              *                                  System.String
```

Result from: Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Service\RootSDDL

```
Name     Value                                                        Type
----     -----                                                        ----
RootSDDL O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GWGX;;;WD)   System.String
```

Result from: Test-WsMan localhost

```
wsmid           : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/identity/1/wsmanidentity.xsd
ProtocolVersion : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd
ProductVendor   : Microsoft Corporation
ProductVersion  : OS: 0.0.0 SP: 0.0 Stack: 2.0
```

This is locally on the server, the remote WORKGROUP clients is not yet involved in this scenario

Comment: run an elevated command prompt and run "winrm /quickconfig" it may give you a more descriptive error message.

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into and solved this problem on a couple of systems. In this particular case, these two systems were not part of a domain, and the user account was not the original "Administrator" account, but rather a newer account that was also a member of the local Administrators group.

The solution came from the following blog post I wandered across: [WinRM Access is Denied on Local Computer](http://www.shirmanov.com/2011/04/winrm-access-is-denied-on-local.html). In short, run the following from a command prompt (launched as Administrator):

```
> reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

After that, re-launch the Powershell prompt as admin and re-run `Enable-PSSRemoting`. That simple.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my trouble shooting guide to fixing this problem, it covers:

- Is your machine connected to a domain or work group?
- Are you logged in as a local Administrator?
- Was PowerShell launched as 'Administrator'?
- Is your password blank?
- Are you trying to connect to a SharePoint farm?
- Is your Server hosted/managed by a Hosting company?
- Are you using VirtualBox?
- Are you running the command on a computer where the language is not
  set to English?

[https://serverfault.com/questions/337905/enabling-powershell-remoting-access-is-denied](https://serverfault.com/questions/337905/enabling-powershell-remoting-access-is-denied/568228#568228)

Answer (score 0):

I can totally reproduce this behavior on a fresh Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 with PowerShell 2

Using an elevated PowerShell, `enable-psremoting -force` results in the `Set-WSManQuickConfig : Access is denied.` error.

The workaround that worked for me was to logon with the real 'administrator' account (S-1-5-...-500) and run the command again.

I don't know why this makes a difference, but it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same errors trying to make PSSession work (Win10Pro to Win10Pro).

Result from `winrm quickconfig`:

```
Message = More data is available.
Error number:  -2147024662 0x800700EA
More data is available.
```

For some strange reason, the `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` registry value was a QWORD rather than a DWORD, so I ran this command and voilà! All is working fine again.

```
> reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

More information is available about [LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/user-account-control-and-remote-restriction) on the Microsoft site.