# winrm access denied for new user

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-command-prompt, winrm

On windows server 2012 was created new user as administrator.
in powershell was started winrm(`winrm quickconfig`).

But after `winrm configSDDL default` result is `WSMan fault: access denied`.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many posts about this exact error message. Here are some excerpts that should help! #LMGTFY :)

**From a Symantec KB:**
https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH200047.html

> This error happens even if the account is a Local Administrator and
>   the command line is run with administrator privileges.
>
> To solve the problem, UAC filtering for local accounts must be disabled by creating the following DWORD registry entry and setting its value to 1:
>
> ```
>  [HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System] LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy
> ```

**From a Microsoft forum:**
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e5f8cfee-d4a6-4e5c-9baf-e8a8a67d9316/winrm-access-denied

> Because of User Account Control (UAC), the remote account must be a
>   domain account and a member of the remote computer Administrators
>   group. If the account is a local computer member of the Administrators
>   group, then UAC does not allow access to the WinRM service. To access
>   a remote WinRM service in a workgroup, UAC filtering for local
>   accounts must be disabled by creating the following DWORD registry
>   entry and setting its value to 1:
>
> ```
> [HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System] LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy
> ```

We do have another unanswered question about this. Maybe they can be merged: 
[Enabling Powershell Remoting, Access is denied?](https://serverfault.com/questions/337905/enabling-powershell-remoting-access-is-denied)